# Most accurate way to find local businesses?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a client who wants his site's users to be able to "check-in" to places, much like Foursquare. I have a basic location-fetching script done, and it stores the latitude and longitude of the user's current location in a database. What would be the most accurate query to get other locations nearby? I'm not entirely sure how I'm supposed to do that correctly (never dealt with location-based sites before).

The basic table structure is like this: id, business_name, lat, long.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should access an API to a service that provides this kind of data.  For example, [Yahoo! Local](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/V3/localSearch.html) or [Google Places](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/).

Basically, you'll be submitting coordinates to their web service, parsing the results, and returning the results in your preferred format to the user.